# Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: decoding stdout: no kind "ExecCredential" is registered for version

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, amazon-eks

**Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: decoding stdout: no kind "ExecCredential" is registered for version "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" in scheme "pkg/client/auth/exec/exec.go:62"
**

```
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  eksctl version 0.111.0
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  using region ap-south-1
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  skipping ap-south-1c from selection because it doesn't support the following instance type(s): t2.micro
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  setting availability zones to [ap-south-1a ap-south-1b]
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  subnets for ap-south-1a - public:192.168.0.0/19 private:192.168.64.0/19
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  subnets for ap-south-1b - public:192.168.32.0/19 private:192.168.96.0/19
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  nodegroup "ng-1" will use "" [AmazonLinux2/1.23]
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  using Kubernetes version 1.23
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  creating EKS cluster "basic-cluster" in "ap-south-1" region with managed nodes
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  will create 2 separate CloudFormation stacks for cluster itself and the initial managed nodegroup
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  if you encounter any issues, check CloudFormation console or try 'eksctl utils describe-stacks --region=ap-south-1 --cluster=basic-cluster'
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  Kubernetes API endpoint access will use default of {publicAccess=true, privateAccess=false} for cluster "basic-cluster" in "ap-south-1"
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  CloudWatch logging will not be enabled for cluster "basic-cluster" in "ap-south-1"
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  you can enable it with 'eksctl utils update-cluster-logging --enable-types={SPECIFY-YOUR-LOG-TYPES-HERE (e.g. all)} --region=ap-south-1 --cluster=basic-cluster'
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  
2 sequential tasks: { create cluster control plane "basic-cluster", 
    2 sequential sub-tasks: { 
        wait for control plane to become ready,
        create managed nodegroup "ng-1",
    } 
}
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  building cluster stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:35:00 [ℹ]  deploying stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:35:30 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:36:01 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:37:01 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:38:01 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:39:01 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:40:01 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:41:02 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:42:02 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:43:02 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:44:02 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:45:02 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:46:03 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-cluster"
2022-09-16 16:48:05 [ℹ]  building managed nodegroup stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-nodegroup-ng-1"
2022-09-16 16:48:05 [ℹ]  deploying stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-nodegroup-ng-1"
2022-09-16 16:48:05 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-nodegroup-ng-1"
2022-09-16 16:48:36 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-nodegroup-ng-1"
2022-09-16 16:49:22 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-nodegroup-ng-1"
2022-09-16 16:49:53 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-nodegroup-ng-1"
2022-09-16 16:51:15 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-nodegroup-ng-1"
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-basic-cluster-nodegroup-ng-1"
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  waiting for the control plane availability...
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [✔]  saved kubeconfig as "/home/santhosh_puvaneswaran/.kube/config"
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  no tasks
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [✔]  all EKS cluster resources for "basic-cluster" have been created
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  nodegroup "ng-1" has 3 node(s)
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  node "ip-192-168-15-31.ap-south-1.compute.internal" is ready
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  node "ip-192-168-35-216.ap-south-1.compute.internal" is ready
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  node "ip-192-168-36-191.ap-south-1.compute.internal" is ready
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  waiting for at least 3 node(s) to become ready in "ng-1"
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  nodegroup "ng-1" has 3 node(s)
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  node "ip-192-168-15-31.ap-south-1.compute.internal" is ready
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  node "ip-192-168-35-216.ap-south-1.compute.internal" is ready
2022-09-16 16:52:09 [ℹ]  node "ip-192-168-36-191.ap-south-1.compute.internal" is ready

*2022-09-16 16:52:10 [✖]  unable to use kubectl with the EKS cluster (check 'kubectl version'): WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: decoding stdout: no kind "ExecCredential" is registered for version "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" in scheme "pkg/client/auth/exec/exec.go:62"* 

2022-09-16 16:52:10 [ℹ]  cluster should be functional despite missing (or misconfigured) client binaries
2022-09-16 16:52:10 [✔]  EKS cluster "basic-cluster" in "ap-south-1" region is ready
santhosh_puvaneswaran@it002072:
```

I don't why I am having this error again and again, [image]

I can create a clusters and delete, But can't able to work on it..!

Answer (score 33):

You need to update your AWS CLI to >2.7.25 or the latest (recommended), ensure your CLI is pointing to the right region, then try `eksctl utils write-kubeconfig --cluster=<name>`. Open the kubeconfig file and check `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1` has changed to `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1`.

Comment: I don't have `eksctl` installed, but this command worked for me instead: `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name=<your-cluster-name>`

Answer (score 15):

For me, it worked with awscli v2

Steps:

```bash
# Download AWS CLI v2
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"

# Un-compress the archive
unzip awscliv2.zip

# Run the installer
sudo ./aws/install
```

Answer (score 9):

For awscli version 2 run:

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install --update
```

Comment: Was facing the same issue, this resolved. Thanks alot!!!!!!!